# Looking for a style swicher

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have for some time a big problem for which I can not finish my work.

I can not implement a **style swicher working**. I recently tried to implement the following:

http://www.cssnewbie.com/jquery-popout-ad-part-3/#.UixD59L0Fe5 , but the link to the plugin used on cookies, there seems to be more available

http://designshack.net/articles/css-style-switcher/: This method I would have liked for its simplicity, but if you click the link, you get redirected to the home page of the server as some have said in the comments of 'article

I finally tried http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/09/09/switching-styles-jquery-css-exchanger/: but I would like something that will work with the links and not with the option tag

If someone wants to read the jsfiddle of this last: **jsfiddle.net/efvNZ/**

Someone **could help** me Explaining how I could adapt this code or even **encouraging me some alternative** , I'd be very grateful

**Thanks in advance to all who help me**

Comment: It is easy enough done but you want a jQuery solution.

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow is not a "give me the code" site, even if you're polite about it (which you are). Make your own attempt and if you run into a *specific* problem doing so, ask a question showing the code you're having trouble with and saying what you expect it to do, what it seems to be doing instead, and why that surprises you.

Comment: Hope I'm not being rude, my sentence was not an order.

I simply asked if anyone could help me to convert that code to fit on a link, while the original seems to be based on the option tag.
But if someone has offesso, I will provide to change my question

Answer (score 1):

Without cookies...

**Head Section** (Styles)

```
<link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" title="main" media="screen">
<link href="/css/alt1.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="alt1" media="screen">
<link href="/css/alt2.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="alt2" media="screen">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function changeStyle(title) {
  var lnks = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
  for (var i = lnks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (lnks[i].getAttribute('rel').indexOf('style')> -1 && lnks[i].getAttribute('title')) {
    lnks[i].disabled = true;
    if (lnks[i].getAttribute('title') == title) lnks[i].disabled = false;
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span onclick="changeStyle('alt1')">1st Stylesheet</span>
<span onclick="changeStyle('alt2')">2nd Stylesheet</span>
```